SSLHandshakeException Exception in Springboot 3 and java-21 migration
I am migrating to Java 21 and Spring Boot 3. Everything is working fine, but I'm unable to call an external API due to an SSLHandshakeException.
Service Param:
EnvironmentFile=/var/www/xxx-xxxx-XXXx/configs/lending-xxx-xxx-env.sh
ExecStart=/bin/java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/lending/xxxx/keys/stage-api-xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=xxxx@xxxx -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=3 -Dnetworkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=3 -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/lending/ccis/oomdump -XX:+UseG1GC -Xss64M -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xlog:gc:/xxx/xxx/gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -jar /var/www/xxxx-xxx-xxx/xxxx-xxxx-xxx.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
ExecStop=/bin/pkill /var/www/xxx-xxx-xxx/xxx-xxx-xxx.jar
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:365) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:287) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:204) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.executeHandshake(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:303) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:251) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:181) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:447) at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:162)
